# 3D plot problem with simple plot

Tags: plotting

I do have an very simple problem with 3D plot which I do not understand. I am trying to make a very simple 3D plot, but it does not give any output. I assume that the mistake is very simple one, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. Here is the input:

```
ListPlot3D[{{1/1000000000, 0., 1.000000000000007}, {1/1000000000, 
  0.00015707963267948965, 0.9999999999763682}, {1/1000000000, 
  0.0003141592653589793, 0.9999999999054519}}].
```

I would be grateful for yours help.

Comment: Try `ListPointPlot3D`

Comment: Unfortunately ListPointPlot3D does not work either I tried it already.

Comment: The orders of magnitude among the coordinate components differ too much, which should be avoided, e.g., by using different units.

Answer (score 3):

It seems `ListPointPlot3D` doesn't like the fact that all points agree in the 3rd coordinate to 10 figures. Manually choosing <s>`PlotRange`</s> `PlotRangePadding` makes it work (the automatic padding in the 3rd dimension that is too small, so let e.g. `PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic, 1/1000}`)

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{1/1000000000, 0., 1.000000000000007},
   {1/1000000000, 0.00015707963267948965, 0.9999999999763682},
   {1/1000000000, 0.0003141592653589793, 0.9999999999054519}},
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[1/50],
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0.999999, 1}},
 PlotRangePadding -> {1, 1/1000000, 1}]
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you for your help Coolwater.

Comment: `PlotRange -> All` does the same; no explicit range required.

Comment: @Edmund You're right. Thank you for the correction